# ORACLE get count time range from both date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I'm using ORACLE, how to get time duration from this below date:

```
SELECT 24 * (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') - TO_CHAR(LASTACTIVITY, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')) diff_hours 
FROM WA_GA_TBL_USERS
```

I got error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

What I want is to get count time range from both date.

Example:

```
SYSDATE = 2017-10-06 17:00
LASTACTIVITY = 2017-10-06 15:30
```

And the result is: 1.5

And for next I will validate it with PHP

```
if($timeduration > 1) //1 means 1 hour
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have date expressions, you don't need to convert them to varchars:

```
SELECT 24 * (SYSDATE - LASTACTIVITY) diff_hours FROM WA_GA_TBL_USERS
```

Comment: For next I will validate it with PHP how can I do that? if($diff_hours > 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    24 * (to_date('2017-10-06 17:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') - to_date('2017-10-06 15:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) as diff_hours
from dual;
```

[image]

Usually i use php with mysql but i don't think the semantic is different the , i didn't try the code below but can be an help for you :

```
<?php
$c = oci_pconnect(...);
$s = oci_parse($c, "select 24 * (to_date('2017-10-06 17:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') - to_date('2017-10-06 15:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) as diff_hours from dual");
oci_execute($s);
$res=oci_fetch_array($s);

if($res >1)
    //..
?>
```

Comment: This is quite different request you are doing , you miss php tag and the title is asking for different problem

Comment: Sorry, I missing it

Comment: Edited , please update the title of this question and add php tag

Comment: Hi Frank, I need to use SYSDATE, when I change 2017-10-06 17:00 to SYSDATE, it show me result: -17627871.5

Comment: Maybe because sysdate <  to_date('2017-10-06 15:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')